# Keel Attachment

Tags: ships

In [Technik Museum Speyer](https://speyer.technik-museum.de/) I have seen **strange attachments to the keel** of Rescue Ship John T. Essberger. What is their purpose? Are they anyhow related to hydrodynamics? They are quite small compared to the size of the ship.

[image: strange attachments to the keel]

Comment: They are sacrificial zinc anodes to prevent corrosion. Every boat has them, big metal boats may have several tons of them.

Comment: https://www.boatzincs.com/teardrop-8.html?gad=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw84anBhCtARIsAISI-xfvns7cD0lOODq9hFoqcqU5tDoiMmbr2JVhej0_v7o2szgeGajaZQAaAiZMEALw_wcB

Comment: @PhilSweet Awesome! I suggest you make your comment into an answer. I will accept that as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are sacrificial zinc anodes to prevent corrosion. Every boat has them, big metal boats may have several tons of them. This type is a strap-on teardrop style.